# iPhone how to implement a "Wide" UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'd like to have a UITableView with cells wider than 320 points. The user should be able to scroll sideways to be able to view different parts of a UITableViewCell. Is this kind of behavior possible with a UITableView, or should I go and try to implement a tiling UIScrollView?

I tried wrapping a UITableView within a UIScrollView, and the results are terrible - they compete for the scroll gestures and most of the time the scroll view wins, preventing the table from being traversed vertically.

Any input is appreciated!

Thank you!

Update: I tried the proposed solution and it scrolls properly, but the tableview is still only 320 pixels wide. Is tableView's width linked to the window bounds ?

Comment: I think if you will disable UIScrollView bounces, make contentsize height and frame height equal to visible rect height (tableview frame height also) it will not scroll vertically, only tableview will. Post your code where you wrap tableView in scrollview please.

Comment: When the user pans right, do you want the CELL to scroll right, or the entire table?

Comment: I'm using storyboards, and the code is simply a UITableView WIthin a UIScrollView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping the table view with the scroll view is the right way.

UIScrollView with

- Show horizontal scrollers
- scrolling enabled
- autosize to full screen

Inside that, a UITableView

- shows vertical scrollers
- scrolling enabled

Then I set the table view's frame, with `w,` being the calculated width of the table view with all columns, whatever your width, and `kTableScrollViewHeight` being the fixed height of both the table view and the scroll view, in my case, for example 367 points (screen minus status, navbar and tabbar):

> ```
> tv.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, w, kTableScrollViewHeight);
> ```

and the scroll view's content size

> ```
> scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(w, kTableScrollViewHeight);
> ```

If you want the scroll-to-top behavior when the user taps the status bar, you might want to set

> ```
> scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
> ```

because otherwise the scroll view will take away the tap from the table view.

Comment: UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView.

Comment: Then why would you put it in another scroll view, if you could just change the properties of the table view?

Comment: the additional scroll view is necessary, because  the UITableView alone won't extend beyond screen width, because it automatically resets its contentSize unless you subclass it, write a category or do other things you're not supposed to. Within the scrollview the tableview will resize itsself according to the surrounding contentSize.

Comment: I will try the scrollview and a tableview solution

Comment: Disabling bouncing worked, the scroll view now scrolls horizontally, the tableview vertically. My tableview is wider than the screen, but it does not seem to fully fill the space available, I'll investigate why

Comment: doesn't it fill the total width or height that you wanted?

Comment: Tried this method, the tableview is scrolling vertically, the scrollview scrolls horizontally. Unfortunately, the tableview is still 320 pixels wide.

Comment: you need to set the tableview's width and the contentsize of the scrollview to the same value. In my example above, that's the variable "w". This could be any value depending on how wide you want your tableview to be.